# Clear JavaScript and CSS cache by add query variable compatibility in all browsers

Tags: javascript, css, browser-cache

I want to ask about clear cache for javascript and css. I used query variables for my js and css to avoid caching in browser. My question is, can we do this method in all type of browsers? Or is there any browser that run differently when we add query variable in js/css?

Comment: That should apply to all browsers, as long as the query string is different each load. That's because it will be recognised as a different URL and the browser will be forced to reload the entire resource without reading from cache. To the browser, `http://a.com/x.js?q=1231` vs `http://a.com/x.js?q=1234` is no different than, say `http://b.com?search=foo` and `http://b.com?search=bar`.

Comment: Makes me want to make my own fork of a browser just to answer *Yes*.

Comment: thank you for the answer @terry.. i just worry that some browser have different behavior..

Comment: @Terry is there any articles or documentation that discuss about this matter? i just want to make sure that this method can be used in all browsers.

Comment: @SudarsonoSung Yes it is known to be reliable. In fact almost all websites take advantage of this for cache busting: https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/#article-header-id-1

Comment: @Terry thank you very much for the info! it really help me to solve this issue..